# google service account - some users not having access even when we have permission for the whole domain

Tags: google-oauth, google-apps-marketplace

We are having domain level permissions for a customer and are using service account for getting access tokens. This is working alright for all users except one and we get access_denied error.

I am trying to access imap api.

Also, what does access_denied error mean? Is there a document that describes each oauth2 error on detail?

Comment: which api are you trying to access?

Comment: edited the question to reflect that. Which api should not really matter though as they would be domain-wide and are working for all but one.

Comment: The thing is I don't understand the question.  If you are using a service account then there is only one user, the service account.  I don't understand what you mean by users having access.  What exactly does your application do, and how is it used?

Comment: service accounts are used to obtain access tokens for marketplace customers. Customer's email address is sent under "sub" field and access token thus obtained is used to query api on customer's behalf. Marketplace installations provide permissions for all users of a domain in one go. So, if one user's access tokens can be fetched, all user's should work. But that is not happening. I am getting access_denied for just one user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get access_denied error for a subset of users if the domain administrator turns off your app for an Organizational Unit (OU) containing the users.

See https://support.google.com/a/answer/182537?hl=en